# Is there any way in xml schema to let an attribute always be greater than another one in an xml element?

Tags: xml, xsd

Here is the `xml`:

```
<range from="100" to="200"/>
```

So, how to write an `xsd` to ensure that the attribute `to` is always larger than `from`?

Answer (score 1):

Schema, by definition will just define the schema of the document, not validate the conditional data. You have to do that in your application.

Answer (score 1):

In XSD 1.1, you can use an assertion on the type of 'range' to impose that constraint.  In XSD 1.0, the constraint is not expressible.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample to see how you can add an XSD 1.1 assert in your case:

```
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:attribute name="to" type="xs:integer"/>
    <xs:attribute name="from" type="xs:integer"/>
    <xs:assert test="@to > @from"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

In the "test" attribute from the "assert" element you can introduce an XPath 2.0 expression.