# xsd: restricting an attribute to be greater than an other (relative validation)

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm searching for a way to restrict the input of an attribute `valid-till` in accordance to the companion attribute `valid-from`.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 
   <xs:complexType name="Data">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="material" type="Material" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID" />
      <xs:attribute name="valid-from" type="xs:dateTime" />
      <xs:attribute name="valid-till" type="xs:dateTime" />
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: Yes indeed. As I am limited to xsd-1.0, there is no solution. As you [mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15800181/1791481).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to start would be doing a web search, or a search on Stack Overflow.  See any or all of

- [Is there any way in xml schema to let an attribute always be greater than another one in an xml element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793221)
- [Validating the child's age against the parents age in xsd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262915)
- [XSD assertions conditioned by the existence of attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24871868)
- [Restrict attribute value depending on value of another attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743510)
- [XSD: Define attributes based on the value of previous attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412224)
- [XML schema attribute dependancies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20701626)

Or search on 'xsd assertion', 'xsd assert', 'xsd co-occurrence constraint'.